# How to Identify Unique Users on a Website?

Tags: asp.net

I have a website and I can collect all kinds of information (log) of the viewer including - but not limited to: `IP`, `Country`, `City`, `OS`, `Date` and `Time`. (If It's a mobile device, it's `MobileOS`, `Device Model` etc.)

However, logs having the same IP adresses does not seem to be useful to identify the viewer since the website is mostly used by the students of my university and they have the same IP address as that of the university's WiFi.

I had the idea to somehow get the MAC Address of the viewer's device, but it does not seem applicable in ASP.NET. (There is a JavaScript solution,but it works only for IE.)

Is there any way to obtain the MAC address of my users? Or is there any other way to uniquely identify users on my website that I could perhaps use?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: MACs don't make it past the router in most cases. Just use a cookie and this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3351921/is-it-possible-to-get-a-unique-identification-number-from-a-mobile-device

Comment: What do you intend to do with the information if you are grabbing their MAC address?  I think some users would be a little concerned that you're tracking them that closely.

Comment: An [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).

Answer (score 3):

You can't get the MAC address because there are lots of machines (and interfaces) between you and the viewer of the website. The IP address, as you're finding, isn't unique because the visitor might be behind a NAT, or might change IP addresses because of lease renewal or temporary assignment.

There are other ways to do fingerprinting, if you're just trying to identify machines (and the users, and the sessions): https://panopticlick.eff.org/static/browser-uniqueness.pdf

You stop short of explaining why you want to get the MAC address. What is it that you want to accomplish?

Comment: I just thought MAC Address is something unique for each device, so that I could distinguish the log having IP1 and MACAddress1 from the one ,having the same IP, IP1 and MACAddress2. You claim that I would get the last machine's MAC Address along the path that the Request is coming from. And I do agree... I'm busy with the pdf,thanks

Comment: PDF moved to https://panopticlick.eff.org/static/browser-uniqueness.pdf